# PHP Libraries to assist with Monero integration

Tags: payment-integration, php

Are there any PHP Libraries available to merchants to make integrating Monero payments easier?

How much time is generally required to integrate a Monero payment infrastructure?

Aside from the decision to keep Monero or convert it to another currency, how much ongoing support is required? Is updating twice a year (when Monero has a hard fork) one of the only times that maintenance will be required?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Any business wanting to accept Monero could contact the community for assistance, ideally no kind of "permission" is required since anyone can use and trade Monero. The idea there is an official structure to support Monero is misleading but the community shall be forthcoming in helping and supporting merchants to integrate Monero since the project's aim is a secure and easy method of transferring wealth.

There are several PHP libraries available with varied degree of quality:

https://github.com/MalMen/PHP-Monero

https://github.com/TheKoziTwo/xmr-integration

https://github.com/PsychicCat/monero-php

https://github.com/monero-integrations/monerophp

Comment: Thank you for the PHP libraries. By "support" I meant work by the merchant to maintain a working daemon, etc.

Answer (score 2):

There is another PHP library developed by serhack.
https://github.com/monero-integrations/monerophp